# Cell is being disappered in tableview on touch

Tags: swift, storyboard, load, tableview, xib

I am using table view in my XIB file and  in my storyboard of class NewsfeedController I need to reuse same table view with its content .
So here is my code

In My Newsfeedcontroller.swift

```
func viewDidLoad 

{

  let controller1 : XibViewController = XibViewController(nibName:"XibViewController",XibViewController bundle: nil

Controller1.view.frame = CGrectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height )

self.view.addSubview(Controller1.view)


}
```

I am able to call all delegates and datasource methods of tableview but While I am tapping on view ,all cells are being disappeared and view is showing up blank. 
     I don't use didSelectRowatIndexpath method in my XibController.

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: I would recommend not using this kind of setup nowadays, it's just outdated unless you have a very specific reason. Setup your controller inside of a storyboard instead. Use autolayout as apposed to frames.

Comment: Actually I have used two xibs in a my storyboard in single view controller

Comment: See the link ...  https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu/tree/master/Demos

Comment: Where I need reuse one of XIB in my View Controller